# "All Meta Sites" selector broken for Stackexchange filters

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

The filter for getting questions from all meta sites seems broken; every time I try to use it the resulting list of questions is emtpy. [Here is one example filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19036/my-filter-3) for getting all questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) on all meta sites, which does not return any question for me. If I change "All Meta Sites" into "All Sites" it returns questions as expected.

This used to work some days ago, and suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now – sorry about that.

Our database table that maintains the full list of sites, including whether or not they are considered *meta sites*, became misconfigured a couple days ago.